# How to get all values of select with multiple choices on GAE-side?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-app-engine, html-select

I have select like below on the client side:

```
<select multiple="multiple" id="reason" class="input-xlarge">
  <option value="001">reason1</option>
  <option value="002">reason2</option>
  <option value="003">reason3</option>
  <option value="004">reason4</option>
  <option value="005">reason5</option>
</select>
```

The data is sent to the server with the code below:

```
var reason = $('#reason').val();
$.ajax({
  data: {'reason': reason},
  ...
});
...
```

And on the server I do:

```
from google.appengine.ext import webapp
from google.appengine.ext.webapp.util import run_wsgi_app
arguments = self.request.arguments()
for argument in arguments:
    if self.request.get(argument):
        self.response.out.write(argument+': '+self.request.get(argument)+'<br>')
```

In result even when several reasons are chosen, I see:

```
reason[]: 002
```

How can I get all values selected?

**Upd1**. They are passed in the request as:

```
reason%5B%5D=001&reason%5B%5D=002&reason%5B%5D=003&reason%5B%5D=004
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I can get all of them with code below (thanks to **lericson** from gae irc):

```
reasons = self.request.get_all('reason[]')
for reason in reasons:
    logging.info(reason)
```

But I don't like it as it assumes hardcoding of the field value on the server side. So, I've modified javascript to send `reason.join()` instead of just `reason`.